# Token is not saving inside the database

Tags: php, wordpress, api, plugins, token

I am writing a plugin for wordpress and have trouble saving the token inside the databse.
This is how I try to save it:

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['the_stuff_go_login_submit'] ) ) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $body = array(
            'credentials' => array(
                'password' => $password,
                'username' => $email,
            ),
        );
        $response = wp_remote_post( 'https://api.print.com/login', array(
            'body' => json_encode( $body ),
            'headers' => array(
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ),
        ) );
        if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
            echo '<p>An error occurred: ' . $response->get_error_message() . '</p>';
        } else {
            $response_body = json_decode( $response['body'], true );
            var_dump($response_body); // added var_dump here
            if ( isset( $response_body['data']['token'] ) ) {
                update_option( 'the_stuff_go_token', $response_body['data']['token'] );
                echo '<p>Login successful. Token saved.</p>';
                echo '<p>Token: ' . $response_body['data']['token'] . '</p>';
                return;
            }
         echo '<p>Login failed. Please check your credentials and try again.</p>';
        }
    }


    ?>
    <h1>Login to Print.com API</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <p>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" required>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" required>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="the_stuff_go_login_submit" value="Login">
        </p> 
    </form>
```

But when I try to retrieve the token with this code:

```
// Render the main menu page
function the_stuff_go_render_page() {

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.print.com/products', [
  'headers' => [
    'accept' => 'application/json',
    //'authorization' => 'Bearer ' . get_option('the_stuff_go_token'),
    'authorization' => 'Bearer HARDCODED TOKEN HERE',
  ],
]);

echo $response->getBody();
}
```

So when I hardcode the token inside  `'authorization' => 'Bearer HARDCODED TOKEN HERE'`
It works and I am able to get A list of the products through the API.
But when I try: `'authorization' => 'Bearer ' . get_option('the_stuff_go_token'),`

I tried getting to token from the database using ECHO but it just says token is not available so this means  it is not saving right.

I tried finding a solution but was not able to.
Its also good to mention that this is my first time working with API and PHP.

Thank you in advance

When retrieving the token it should give me access to the product list
but instead the token can not be saved or retrieved correcrtly.

Comment: update_option should return true or false based on whether it succeeded or not, so start by checking that.

Comment: @CBroe The option returns false so does this mean its not saving?
This is what I see when clicking on option:

The token is not available.

The token is not available.

API Options
GET option:

POST option:

Comment: Are you talking about the result of the `update_option` call now, or about the attempt to fetch it via `get_option`?

Comment: @CBroe I am talking about the function render_option.
```
function the_stuff_go_render_options() {


    // GGET and POST 
    $get_option = get_option('the_stuff_go_get_option');
    $post_option = get_option('the_stuff_go_post_option');

    // Check if the token exists
    if (!empty($token)) {
        echo '<p>The token is: ' . $token . '</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>The token is not available.</p>';
    }

    // Display the GET and POST options
    echo '<h2>API Options</h2>';
    echo '<p>GET option: ' . $get_option . '</p>';
    echo '<p>P
```

Comment: Yes, `get_option` will return false, if the option can't be found (and you didn't specify any other value it should return in this case.) So you'll have to debug the part where you tried to _set_ it, because it looks like that did not work properly to begin with.

Comment: so the problem should be the way I save it?
I get the token during the  var_dump($response_body);
but it shows like this: string(655) "eyJhbGci...(rest of the token)
this is how to save in  wordpress right?:             update_option( 'the_stuff_go_token', $response_body['data']['token'] );

Comment: Well if `$response_body` was a string value, then trying to access `$response_body['data']['token']` can hardly make any sense. Most likely your if condition there is false, so that `update_option` was never actually called in the first place. (In which case you should have never gotten to see your `Login successful. Token saved.` message you are outputting there either. Did you? And if not, then why were you not able to draw the _logical_ conclusion from that?)